# Pulling data from external Active Directory in Django

Tags: python, django, active-directory, ldap

I currently have an app that uses a MySQL backend and I have a client that has profile information for its users stored on it but they also have Active Directory and want to know if I can pull information from that as well to retrieve information from there for a specific profile. I know that you can configure Django for multiple SQL database connections or substitute the authentication backend to Active Directory.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/

https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/

But what I was wondering if I could do both MySQL and Active Directory at the same time or do I just need to connect to the Active Directory externally and retrieve the information that way?

Is this do-able and if so which would be the best way to approach it?

Comment: You can write a management command that will synchronize profiles stored in the database with data from Active Directory. Or authentication backend that will do it. Or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar situation with a Django site I administer. Here's the Django App I use:

https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap

It allows me to use PostgreSQL for my database, and pull the user metadata I need out of Active Directory and into the user record by mapping fields. It is the best method I have found after several false starts.

If you're just looking to pull data from Active Directory and not into the Django user, here's the package and a code sample I've found to work:

Python 3 package: git+https://github.com/rbarrois/python-ldap.git@py3

Example, which you can modify to work with Django's ORM:

```
"""
This code provide an example of how to connect to LDAP (specifically, Active Directory)
using Python 3.

Requires python-ldap3, available via the following command:
pip install git+https://github.com/rbarrois/python-ldap.git@py3
"""

import ldap

LDAP_URI = 'ldap://ldap.server.com'
LDAP_DN = 'dc=server,dc=com'
LDAP_USERNAME = 'ldap_user@server.com'
LDAP_PASSWORD = ''
USER_NAME = 'username-to-test'
USER_IN_GROUP = 'CN=SomeGroup,DC=server,DC=com'
USER_NOT_IN_GROUP = 'CN=SomeGroupThatDoesNotExist,DC=server,DC=com'

try:
    # Connect to LDAP / Active Directory
    ldap_con = ldap.initialize(LDAP_URI)
    ldap_con.protocol_version = 3
    ldap_con.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
    ldap_con.simple_bind_s(LDAP_USERNAME, LDAP_PASSWORD)

    # sAMAAccountName is Active Directory's 'username'
    user_filter='(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=' + USER_NAME + '))'
    attrs = ['memberOf']

    # Perform the search.
    ldap_user = ldap_con.search_s(LDAP_DN, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, user_filter, attrs)

    # Active Directory returns a list of byte literals. Convert them to strings in a more sensibly named list.
    ldap_groups = []
    for value in ldap_user[0][1]['memberOf']:
        ldap_groups.append(value.decode('utf-8'))

    # Print the LDAP groups the user above is a member of, one per line.
    for value in ldap_groups:
        print(value)

    # Perform check to see whether a user is in a group, or explicitly, a user it not in a group.
    if USER_IN_GROUP in ldap_groups:
         print(USER_NAME + " is a member of " + USER_IN_GROUP)
    else:
         print(USER_NAME + " is not a member of " + USER_IN_GROUP)

    if USER_NOT_IN_GROUP in ldap_groups:
         print(USER_NAME + " is a member of " + USER_NOT_IN_GROUP)
    else:
         print(USER_NAME + " is not a member of " + USER_NOT_IN_GROUP)

    # Unbind from LDAP / Active Directory.
    ldap_con.unbind()
except ldap.LDAPError:
    print(ldap.LDAPError)
```

These two lines are essential when connecting to Active Directory using an LDAP package:

```
ldap_con.protocol_version = 3
ldap_con.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
```

Comment: Yea, I just need to pull the data and display it in a View. That's it.